# Blackberry Phonegap geolocation Issues

Tags: blackberry, cordova, geolocation, blackberry-webworks

I'm having a problem when testing the `geolocation API` using the Blackberry devices. I'm using `Phonegap 1.2.0` to build my app and I use the common `HTML 5 geolocation API` to get the location information.

I'm testing using **Bold 9900** device on `wi-fi` and rarely I could get the lat long. Most of the time it returns time out error. Using the simulator, I get everything running smoothly, my google map shows up just fine. Even when I test using other devices like **Torch 9860 on wi-fi**, I have to retry many times until I get the lat long. On Bold 9900, it just time out all the time. I checked the device location service from the Settings and I actually could see that the device GPS working, the lat long were detected fine. This must be something wrong with the Blackberry devices, the exact same codes I have running fine on iPhone.

I tested using the SIM card as well to make sure is not the wi-fi causing the problem, but the same thing happens. It just can't get the lat long right away, only when you're lucky.

As recommended by *Blackberry Webworks*, I do not need to specify permissions or feature elements inside the config file. My code is just as simple as this one:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, { maximumAge: 600000, 
timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

var success = function(position) { // do something };

var error = function(e) { // do something };
```

Can someone help me on this?? Before I throw my Blackberry devices...